# Retrieving classpath value in ant build.xml file

Tags: java, linux, ant

i'm new to ant and i wrote this to retrieve the classpath :

```
  <!--
  ## ************************************************************************** 
  ## ENVIRONMENT DEFINITION 
  -->
  <path id="classpath">
    <pathelement path="${env.CLASSPATH}" />
 </path> 
 <property name="extdirs" value="${env.EXTDIRS}" />
```

It works on Ubuntu and not on Fedora :
here's the value of my classpath :

```
 echo $CLASSPATH 
/opt/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/amira/workspace/classes
```

I tried to use the attribute location of pathelement but it doesn't work on Fedora also:

```
  <pathelement location="${env.CLASSPATH}" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you have CLASSPATH set on the Fedora account? There's nothing specific to Fedora which would make this fail.

Comment: Yes i'm sure because it works when i compile with a Gnu MakeFile (using the same classpath variable)

Answer (score 1):

Ant has access to all [Java properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29), so you may use :

```
<echo>
 ${java.class.path}
 ${java.ext.dirs}
</echo>
```

Beside that, Ant has also [predefined properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#built-in-props).

**EDIT after comment**

try with :

```
<property environment="env"/>     
<path id="classpath">
 <pathelement path="${env.CLASSPATH}"/>
</path>

<property name="extdirs" value="${env.EXTDIRS}"/>
<dirname file="${ant.file}" property="antfiledirname"/>

<echo>
 Classpath 1 => ${ant.refid:classpath}
 Classpath 2 => ${env.CLASSPATH}
 ExtDIRS     => ${env.EXTDIRS}
 AntFileDirName => ${ antfiledirname}
</echo>
```

The output of Classpath 1 and Classpath 2 is essentially the same, with the little
difference that the first entry in Classpath 1 is the full qualified path to your antfile
- means dirname of ${ant.file} = ${antfiledirname} in the example snippet – whereas in Classpath 2 it’s ‘.’

Comment: it displays this                                             [echo]   /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_01/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
 Which is not the same classpath i'm looking for :                 echo $CLASSPATH 
/opt/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/amira/workspace/classes